# changing form action by input options

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am beginner programmer who need a professional advice about java.
I am trying to change my form action by input data.
Like, my form action is "http://ddd.com" and if I input 'abc' then it changes to 
http://ddd.com/abc
this is what I have so far...

```
<body>
  <form action="http://ddd.com"+"/"+"addr1"+"/"+"addr2", id="frm">
  <input type="text" name=addr1>
  <input type="text" name=addr2>
  <input type="submit" onclick=(this.form.frm.value)>
  </form>
</body>
```

Please give me an answer. Thanks :)

Comment: do you mind giving the result you have in mind? are you trying to grab the data from codeigniter? If this is the case I would suggest building the URL as http://ddd.com/index.php?addr1=xxxx&addr2=xxxx codeigniter can grab this format easily.. Tying to do it how you are doing it will make it very hard to get the information out...

Comment: if i enter abc and def then it pops up "http://ddd.com/abc/def" like this

Answer (score 0):

You can call a javascript function on form submit and inside that function you can access all input values to create a new url and then make  ajax call. 
Eg :

```
<form name="search" onsubmit="return makeSearch()" >
  Name: <input type="text" name="name1"/>
  Age: <input type="text" name="age1"/>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

function makeSearch() {
 // Get values from input fields to create your url
  alert("Code to make AJAX Call");
  return false;
}
```

Make sure that your javascript function should return false in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

1.Get the from's `action` attribute.

2.When the value of input field changes add change `EventListener` and make a new form action with the input field value.And submit the form.

```js
input = document.querySelectorAll('input');//get all input elements
form = document.querySelector('#frm');//get form 
formaction = form.getAttribute('action');//get form's current action
//alert(formaction);
input.forEach(function(input,index){//add event listener for each input
input.addEventListener('change',function(){

var value = this.value;//get changed input field value
var finalaction = formaction+"\/"+value;//make a final action of your form 
console.log(finalaction); 
form.setAttribute('action',finalaction); //set final action as current action
form.submit();//finally submit your from
});
  
 });
```

```html
<form action="http://ddd.com" id="frm">
  <input type="text" name=addr1>
  <input type="text" name=addr2>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

See JS fiddle  here [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hek_Mat/8Lr50w6r/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#frm).submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    var addr1 = document.getElementsByName("addr1")[0].value;
    var addr2 = document.getElementsByName("addr2 ")[0].value;
    var url = "http://ddd.com"+"/"+addr1+"/"+addr2;
    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: url,
     success:function(data){
            //your other codes here
    });

});
```

You need jquery here

Answer (score 0):

First: Assign the input to variables.

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var text1 = input[0].text, text2 = input[1].text;
```

Then: assign the form element to a variable.

```
var form = document.getElementById("frm");
```

Third: Define a function to be called when `submit` is clicked that will add the text to the form's `action` attribute.

```
    function sub(){
    form.action += text1 + text2;
 }document.getElementById("submit"). onclick = "sub()";
```

This way, your action will be changed after the function is.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't add comments to your question, so I'll respond here.

I think you might be going about the problem incorrectly. If you are using the form to submit to codeigniter you can just pass the values as a regular GET or POST. If you are just "linking" to a codeigniter page and need to pass the route then you can do that with location.href

But to answer your question above, you would do something like this:

```js
var frm = document.getElementById('frm'),
    addr1 = document.getElementById('addr1'),
    addr2 = document.getElementById('addr2'),
    btn = document.getElementById('submit'),
    baseAction = frm.action;

btn.addEventListener('click',function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
  
  var frmAction = baseAction,
      addr1Val = addr1.value.trim(),
      addr2Val = addr2.value.trim();

   
  
  if(addr1Val != '') {
    frmAction += addr1.value.trim();
  }
  
  if(addr2Val != '') {
    frmAction += "/" + addr2Val;
  }
  
  console.log(frmAction);
  
  // Below would be used to submit the form
  // frm.action = frmAction;
  // frm.submit()
  
  // OR you could just link out like this ...
  // location.href = frmAction;
  
});
```

```html
  <form action="http://ddd.com" id="frm">
  <input type="text" name="addr1" id="addr1">
  <input type="text" name="addr2" id="addr2">
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
  </form>
```